# Pandas Read Continuously Growing CSV File

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a continuously growing CSV File, that I want to periodically read. I am also only interested in new values.

I was hoping to do something like:

```
file_chunks = pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize=1)
while True:
    do_something(next(file_chunks))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

in a frequency, that is faster than the .csv file is growing.
However, as soon as the iterator does not return a value once, it "breaks" and does not return values, even if the .csv file has grown in the meantime.

Is there a way to read continuously growing .csv files line by line?

Comment: Reading a file while its being written can be challenging. You may find read or write fails because the other side isn't using shared mode or that you have a partially written file that hasn't been flushed yet. If you control both sides, having a file lock protocol can be helpful. Another option it to dedicate a directory to the CSV and have the writer create new files for write.

Comment: I think pandas handles this internally; at least I don't have any problems even at much higher speeds than what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

you could build a `try: except:` around it or make and if statement that checks `if file_chunks is not none` first.
Like this it shouldnt break anymore and he only sleeps when he there are no more chunks left.

```
while True:
    file_chunks = pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize=1)
    while True:
        try:
            do_something(next(file_chunks))
        except:
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work, since the iterator stops iterating if it reaches the end of the file once.

Comment: maybe you could pack the pd.read_csv also into another while loop :) see edit above,  but im also pretty sure that there are move pythonic ways to do that

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to do with the standard `csv` module where you can write your own line iterator that knows how to read an updating file. This generator would read in binary mode so that it can track file position, close the file at EOF and poll its size for appended data. This can fail if the reader gets a partial file update because the other side hasn't flushed yet, or if a CSV cell contains and embedded new line that invalidates the reader's assumption that a binary mode newline always terminates a row.

```
import csv
import time
import os
import threading
import random

def rolling_reader(filename, poll_period=.1, encoding="utf-8"):
    pos = 0
    while True:
        while True:
            try:
                if os.stat(filename).st_size > pos:
                    break
            except FileNotFoundError:
                pass
            time.sleep(poll_period)
        fp = open(filename, "rb")
        fp.seek(pos)
        for line in fp:
            if line.strip():
                yield line.decode("utf-8")
        pos = fp.tell()

# ---- TEST - thread updates test.csv periodically
class GenCSVThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, csv_name):
        super().__init__(daemon=True)
        self.csv_name = csv_name
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        val = 1
        while True:
            with open(self.csv_name, "a") as fp:
                for _ in range(random.randrange(4)):
                    fp.write(",".join(str(val) for _ in range(4)) + "\n")
                    val += 1
            time.sleep(random.random())

if os.path.exists("test.csv"):
    os.remove("test.csv")
test_gen = GenCSVThread("test.csv")

reader = csv.reader(rolling_reader("test.csv"))
for row in reader:
    print(row)
```

A platform dependent update would be to use a facility such as inotify to trigger reads off of a file close operation to reduce the risk of partial data.

Comment: This seems like the way to go. From someone who is not familiar with python, will this keep running no matter what happens once the rolling_reader starts?

Comment: @Jhonathan - yes, as long as there isn't a file error.